# Check if values of Dictionary contains an element with certain field value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, BinaryAssetExtensionDto> _identityMap;
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
if(_identityMap.Values.Contains(x => x.extension == extension))...
```

Is this possible because previous code doesn't work.

Now I'm doing it like this:

```
var result = _identityMap.Values.ToList().Find(x => x.extension == extension);
if (result != null) return result;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;
...
_identityMap.Values.Any(x=>x.extension==extension)
```

Comment: Does it return null if none are found?

Comment: @Lieven it returns boolean if any element in collection meets predicate.

Answer (score 3):

```
return _identityMap.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.extension == extension);
```

This may return null if the condition is not satisfied. If this is not what you want you may provide a default value:

```
return _identityMap.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.extension == extension) ?? 
    new BinaryAssetExtensionDto();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that either of the following would work for you:

```
if (_identityMap.Values.Where(x => x.extension == extension).Count() > 0) { /*...*/ }

if (_identityMap.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.extension == extension) != null)  { /*...*/ }
```

There are probably other possible alternatives too